# Multiple Segue and Number Passing Not Working

Tags: ios

I have code that prints out different PDFs depending on what table row is picked.  I developed this using StoryBoards and use Segues.  I started with prepareForSegue, and shifted to performSegueWithIdentifier because I need several segues from one TableViewController.  I can either: (1) get the row value (integer) passed, buth the webView pdf load doesn’t work (with the vc2 code), or (2) I can load the webView pdf, but not pass the row value with the performSegueWithIndentifier (so only the row = 0 pdf loads).  After a solid week of research and trying, I remained perplexed.  There is something fundamental here that I don’t understand.  Please help.

```
FirstViewController

-   (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    int row = [myIndexPath row];

if (row == 0){
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showView1" sender:self];}

    else if (row == 1){
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showView1" sender:self];}

    else if (row == 2){
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showView2" sender:self];}

SecondViewController *vc2 = [[SecondViewController alloc]init];
vc2.row = row;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc2 animated:YES];




SecondViewController

if (row == 0) {
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cover" ofType:@"pdf"];
        pdfUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
        NSLog(@"in SecondView Controller path =: %@", pdfUrl);}

    else if(row == 1){
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"welcome" ofType:@"pdf"];
        pdfUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
        NSLog(@"in SecondView Controller path =: %@", pdfUrl);}

    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:pdfUrl]];
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do, but doing both performSegueWithIdentifier and pushViewController in didSelectRowAtIndexPath is most likely wrong. Where do "showView1" and "showView2" take you (to which view controllers)?

Comment: Thank you. Didn't use pSWI and pVC together.  Tried both approaches separately. Each had a flaw.  pVC passed the row value and correct pdf name, but webView wouldn't load the pdf.  No row value transfer with pSWI. So same pdf each time. ShowView1 is a segue to the SecondViewController that will display different PDFs depending on the row value chosen the FirstViewController (why I need the row value passed).  I put in the ShowView2 because I will add ThirdViewController ultimately (just not now).  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use prepareForSegue along with performSegueWithIdentifier. So, in the performSegueWithIdentifier:sender: method, pass the selected indexPath as the sender:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   if (indexPath.row < 2) [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showView1" sender:indexPath];
   if (indexPath.row == 2) [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showView2" sender:indexPath];
}
```

Then, use prepareForSegue to pass the row information:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(NSIndexPath *)selectedIndexPath {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showView1"]) {
        SecondViewController *vc2 = segue.destinationViewController;
        vc2.row = selectedIndexPath.row;
    }else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showView2"]) {
        //do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU!  THANK YOU!  That worked perfectly, and taught me a lot.  This is the first time I've used stack overflow.  Am I suppose to vote or do a rating?  You get AAA+++ in my book.

Comment: @user2353906, you can up vote (if you're allowed, I don't know if it takes a certain number of reputation points to do that), and you can accept the answer by clicking on the large hollow arrow.

Comment: Will do.  And, again...Thank you.